# Finding a XML element with a variable/changing location using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Using XSLT, I need to locate the *tag* element from an XML file to start doing the wanted transformations. The *tag* element is typically the root element.

```
<tag>
   ...
</tag>
```

However, a new collection of XML files arrived and some of them have the *tag* element somewhere else. (its location vary from file to file)

```
<a>
  <b>
    <tag>
      ...
    </tag>
  </b>
</a>
```

I would like to know if its possible to obtain the full path/name of *tag* and store it into a variable, so I could use *$tagPath* instead of */a/b/tag*. I tried using the name() function but it only returns the element name (tag).

Thanks!

Comment: would xpath-selector '//tag' help? It matches tag elements at arbitrary levels in the file, and knowing the exact path would become obsolete, right?

Comment: Will there only be one occurrence of `tag` in the entire document? If yes, you could use `//tag` to select it - without knowing (or needing to know) the full path,

Comment: @michael.hor257k There might have more than one. In those cases, there will have a top-level one (the one described) and some others deeper in the tree.

Comment: Well, then `//tag[1]` should work for selecting the top one. Mind you, it's not a very efficient method, but if you don't know the explicit path...

Comment: Do you mean `(//tag)[1]` @michael.hor257k?

Comment: @DanielHaley Actually, I meant `/descendant::tag[1]` - but oops anyway and thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments above, to find the `tag` element regardless of position, you can just use `\\tag`.

If you need the full path of this element, you can use the solution proposed here: [How do you output the current element path in XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953197/how-do-you-output-the-current-element-path-in-xslt).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="text()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//tag">
      <xsl:call-template name="genPath" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="genPath">
      <xsl:param name="prevPath" />
      <xsl:variable name="currPath" select="concat('/',name(),'[',count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])+1,']',$prevPath)" />
      <xsl:for-each select="parent::*">
        <xsl:call-template name="genPath">
          <xsl:with-param name="prevPath" select="$currPath" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:if test="not(parent::*)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$currPath" />      
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can see an example of this here: http://fiddle.frameless.io/